# get html content using jsoup

Tags: javascript, jsoup

I am not able to get the data from the below content using jsoup. Can you please suggest me how to get the title,date,href,description of that href using jsoup. Please suggest me using javascript how can i handle it. Finally i should have two rows with the above specified columns which is under div tag. I have tried it by using this way

```
Jsoup = org.jsoup.Jsoup;
Whitelist = org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist;
OutputSettings = org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings;
EscapeMode = org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.EscapeMode;
doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
os = OutputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml).charset("utf-8"); 
var title = doc.outputSettings(os).select("a[href]").text();
var links = doc.outputSettings(os).select("a").attr("href");
```

But after writing that i got everything in one row. Along with that is there any we can get hyperlink description. I want two rows for the below data.

```
<div class="section"> 
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-sm-12"> 
  <p>Dec 18, 2014, 11:00 ET</p> 
  <ul> 
   <li><a title="SANS Honors People Who Made a Difference in Cybersecurity in 2014" href="http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/sans-honors-people-who-made-a-difference-in-cybersecurity-in-2014-300011928.html">SANS Honors People Who Made a Difference in Cybersecurity in 2014</a></li> 
   <li> SANS Institute is pleased to announce the winners of the SANS 2014 Difference Makers awards. While the headlines focus on security breaches, there are thousands of security practitioners out there who are quietly succeeding and keeping their companies and customers safe from attacks. The SANS... </li> 
   <li>More news about: <a title="SANS Institute">SANS Institute</a> </li> 
  </ul> 
 </div> 
</div> 
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-sm-9"> 
  <p>Dec 17, 2014, 07:00 ET</p> 
  <ul> 
   <li><a title="Microsemi's Ultra-secure SmartFusion2 SoC FPGAs and IGLOO2 FPGAs Recognized on EDN's List of Hot 100 Products of 2014" href="http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/microsemis-ultra-secure-smartfusion2-soc-fpgas-and-igloo2-fpgas-recognized-on-edns-list-of-hot-100-products-of-2014-300010576.html">Microsemi's Ultra-secure SmartFusion2 SoC FPGAs and IGLOO2 FPGAs Recognized on EDN's List of Hot 100 Products of 2014</a></li> 
   <li>  Microsemi Corporation (Nasdaq: MSCC), a leading provider of semiconductor solutions differentiated by power, security, reliability and performance, today announced its SmartFusion2® SoC FPGAs and IGLOO2® FPGAs were recognized among the Hot 100 Products of 2014 by EDN. Among the many... </li> 
   <li>More news about: <a title="Microsemi Corporation">Microsemi Corporation</a> </li> 
  </ul> 
 </div> 
 <div class="col-sm-3"> 
  <a title="Microsemi's Ultra-secure SmartFusion2 SoC FPGAs and IGLOO2 FPGAs Recognized on EDN's List of Hot 100 Products of 2014" href="http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/microsemis-ultra-secure-smartfusion2-soc-fpgas-and-igloo2-fpgas-recognized-on-edns-list-of-hot-100-products-of-2014-300010576.html"> <img src="http://photos.prnewswire.com/prnthumb/20110909/MM66070LOGO" alt="Microsemi Corporation."> </a> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: You should provide code that you have attempted, otherwise it just looks like you want someone to do your work and write the code for you

Comment: I have added my code..

Comment: I don't know anything about jsoup but would guess that `links` would be an array that you would need to loop over to get attributes for each element. For example in jQuery if you get text for a collection of elements ( without loop) it is all text for all elements in one big string

Comment: Are you trying to call jsoup from javascript?